# The currents homology of closed orientable surfaces and Birkhoff Ergodic theorem?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I just know very little about currents but I need vexedly. Thanks for your help.

Let $M$ be a closed orientable surface and $I=(f_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ be an isotopies from identity to $f$. Suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $M$ and $f$ preserves the measure $\mu$. Let $I.z$ be the oriented trajectory of $z$. We can define the 1-current [I.z] (if $I$ is smooth and $I.z$ is simple, it is a 1-sub-manifold of $M$).
If $\rho_I(\mu)=\int_M [I.z] \, d\mu$=0, we call $I$ is $\mu$-hamiltonian. 
My question is that the space of 1-currents is finite dimension? And the first current homology is isomorphic to the standard singular homology $H_1(M,\mathbb{R})$?  Further, can we use the Birkhoff Ergodic theory to the space of 1-currents? I mean, for example, is the following limit
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[I.(f^i(z))]$$ $\mu$-a.e. exists as $n\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: you cannot integrate a 1-current against a measure, the current formalism is not adapted here

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is that the space of 1-currents is finite 
>   dimension?

There are several versions of currents. The most standard definition is
the dual space of the space of k-forms of certain regularity. It is
definitely infinite-dimensional, except in some very degenerate cases (e.g. dimension of the space is 0)

Roughly-speaking 1-current is something
you can integrate against 1-forms, e.g. any formal linear combination of
oriented 1D submanifolds will do or, more generally, 1D submanifolds with a
measures on them, tangent vector-fields with measure-coefficients, etc.

> And the first current homology is isomorphic to the 
>   standard singular
>   homology $H_1(M,\mathbb{R})$?

Yes, once you use definitions, that turn spaces of currents into a complex.

If  trajectory $I.z$ is not rectifiable, then, strictly speaking, it does not
give you a 1-current. On the other hand, it seems, that you only need
the homology class of the rotation vector $\rho_I(\mu)$ to be 0, not $\rho$ itself. Is it right?
If so, would the modified definition work for your purposes?
$$
  \rho_I(\mu) := \int_{M} [\gamma_{z}] d\mu
$$
where $\gamma_{z}$ is the **unique** geodesic from $z$ to $f(z)$ homotopic to
$I.z$ rel endpoints, taken with
respect to some fixed auxiliary metric of non-positive curvature on $M$. If $I.z$ were rectifiable, then $([I.z]-[\gamma_{z}])$ is
a boundary, thus new definition of $\rho$ preserves its homology class in that case. You have to check, that $z\mapsto[\gamma_z]$ is measurable, which, I believe it is, because the space of geodesic intervals is in one-to-one correspondence with pairs of points, (up to deck transformations) in the universal cover of $M$ in a measurable way.

For the same reason, I believe, (but did not verify) that the Birkhoff theorem will hold once the summands are changed to $[\gamma_{f^i(z)}]$ and the considered space of currents is complete.

Comment: @Matveev Thanks  a lot for your answer. Could you give me some references about the result "$\gamma_z$ is the unique geodesic from $z$ to $f(z)$ homotopic to $I.z$ rel endpoints, taken with respect to some fixed auxiliary metric of non-positive curvature on $$".